# How to manage success/failure of independent scheduled jobs in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a few independent scheduled CI jobs.

1. Check that the infrastructure matches Terraform code.
2. Check for npm vulnerabilities.
3. Check that external APIs pass tests.

These are not hermetic. They do not test the fitness of the code in isolation. They could succeed at commit 12345 and then fail at commit 12345 and then succeed again.

I run these daily.

Gitlab lacks the ability to have multiple pipeline types (unlike, say, Buildkite), so I use a variable to control which steps run.

However, I am left with the problem that these checks interfere with the main passed/failed status of commits.

For example, if the Terraform infra check fails, then it's broken and people are notified and whoever is the next to push is informed they fixed it.

These kinds of checks can't be that uncommon, right? How should thse be managed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `allow_failure` keyword.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

> When allow_failure is set to true and the job fails, the job shows an orange warning in the UI. However, the logical flow of the pipeline considers the job a success/passed, and is not blocked.

```
job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - execute_script_that_will_fail
  allow_failure: true
```